# Novel or novella involving a protagonist who travels forward in time and encounters a strange war where the weapons were all color-coded

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel, warfare

The main protagonist travels forward in time and encounters a strange war where the weapons were all color-coded. Like, fire weapons were red, etc. The time traveller might have eventually "looped" time and started back where he started. This novel/novella was probably from the '50s or '60s-era.

Comment: Poul Anderson's "Flight to Forever" is a 1950 novella about a guy who travels forward in time, encounters wars, and eventually goes all around the circle of time and back to his starting point. But there are no color-coded weapons, so **not the one you're looking for**.

Comment: Obligatory mention that, when you return, you can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 5):

In "Time Machine II" by George Pal and Joe Morhaim, the Blitz-born son of the Time Traveler and Weena has modernized his father's invention and is helping the remnants of far-future humanity defend itself against giant mutant bees. He finds a cache of assorted weapons from some long-forgotten conflict:
"Chris looked at the rifle in his hand and understood; the blue color represented frozen destruction, while the red-colored weapon he used in the arsenal was a heat gun." (Dell, 1981, pg. 139) Later in the struggle, there are yellow rifles that are nerve weapons and green ones that use sonic waves.

Comment: Hmm.  That 1981 Dell printing is the only one, so it's not a 50s/60s book; on the other hand it's described as a sequel to the 1960 movie *The Time Machine* so it may have inherited a 60's sensibility from that.